# simplifying nested grouping expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have holes in my math because I didn't pay attention when I was a kid.( so please explain in detail if possible <3 )

Ill write my steps, and please tell me where my error is, and if possible what I should be learning ( math is vast and I have bits and pieces )

50-{2-[11+3${(-1-3)^2}$}

we start with the inner most parenthesis
${(-1-3)^2}$ == ${(-4)^2}$ == ${(-16)}$
so now
[11+3${(-16)}$ == ${11+3*-16}$ == ${11+(-48}$ ==

and now I get stuck .. do I keep the larger number's sign ? and add 11 to -48 ?

Comment: Be careful: What is $(-4)^2$ ? It's $(-4)\times (-4) = +16$ since $-1 \times -1 = +1$. Note that it is different from $-4^2$, which is $-4 \times 4 = -16$. Squaring applies to what is *directly before it*. So if there are parentheses before it, then it's applied to the expression in the parentheses.

Comment: Oki fair enough thank you !
so it becomes 11+3*16 == 59
then 50-{2-[59] == 50-{57} ==  -7?

Comment: Your expression has unmatched parentheses, a fatal error.

Comment: oh oki .. I thought it would make it faster and easier to read ( might've been the lazy me tho lol ) thanks for the input Gerry !

Comment: @Moath - Your should edit your question to fix the parentheses problem. Lazily written questions often get closed, and too many bad questions can lead to losing posting privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start the problem correctly with the inner most parenthesis.
(I assume the problem you mean is $ 50-\{2-[11+3(−1−3)^2]\} $ by the way.)

However, as has been pointed out already $ (-4)^2 = 16$.
So you end up with $ 50-\{2-[11+3*16]\} $.
The next step is evaluating the new inner most bracket $ [11+3*16] $. It is important to first multiply $ 3*16 = 48 $ and only then adding the numbers up to get $11+48 = 59$.
So we have $ 50-\{2-59\} $. We calculate again the inner most bracket to get $ 2-59 = -57 $ to end up with $ 50- \{-57\} $. Since we have a $ - $, before the parenthesis, we need to change the signs of every number in the bracket (here that is only -57) and change the $-$ in front of the bracket to a $+$.
So we end up with $ 50 + 57 = 107 $.
I hope this was helpful.